# tokenize a list of IDs and look them up with a key

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a list of people in `people.xml`, which contain references to family relations in attributes `@trait` and `@rel`. Thus the entries are recursive to the list, where `@rel` contains `@xml:id`.

```
<person xml:id="person_a">
 <firstname>John</firstname>
 <lastname>Foo</lastname>
 <trait type="spouse_of" rel="#person_b">
 <trait type="parent_of" rel="#person_c #person_d">
<person>
<person xml:id="person_b">
 <firstname>Sarah</firstname>
 <lastname>Foo</lastname>
 <trait type="spouse_of" rel="#person_a">
 <trait type="parent_of" rel="#person_c #person_d">
<person>
<person xml:id="person_c">
 <firstname>Henry</firstname>
 <lastname>Foo</lastname>
 <trait type="child_of" rel="#person_a #person_b">
 <trait type="sibling_of" rel="#person_d">
<person>
<person xml:id="person_d">
 <firstname>Tom</firstname>
 <lastname>Foo</lastname>
 <trait type="child_of" rel="#person_a #person_b">
 <trait type=sibling_of" rel="#person_c">
<person>
....
```

Using XSL 3.0/Saxon, I am trying to output the family relations into the following format:

```
<perslist>
<person>
 <name>John Foo</name>
 <relation>spouse of Sarah Foo</relation>
 <relation>parent of Henry Foo, Tom Foo</relation>
</person>
<person>
 <name>Sarah Foo</name>
 <relation>spouse of John Foo</relation>
 <relation>parent of Henry Foo, Tom Foo</relation>
</person>
<person>
 <name>Henry Foo</name>
 <relation>child of John Foo, Sarah Foo</relation>
 <relation>sibling of Tom Foo</relation>
</person>
<person>
 <name>Tom Foo</name>
 <relation>child of John Foo, Sarah Foo</relation>
 <relation>sibling of Henry Foo</relation>
</person>
...
</perslist>
```

Most of this is done and functions, but I am having trouble working with `@rel`  because it can contain multiple values.

I am using a key to lookup the `xml:id`s.  I am trying to use `tokenize()` to split up the ids contained in `@rel`but I'm not having any success.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="3.0">


<xsl:key name="ids" match="person" use="@xml:id"/>

....

<xsl:template match="trait">
    <xsl:variable name="trt" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".[@type='spouse_of']">
            <relation>spouse of 
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($trt/@rel, ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/firstname, key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/lastname" separator=", "/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </relation>
        </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test=".[@type='parent_of']">
            <relation>parent of 
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($trt/@rel, ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/firstname, key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/lastname"  separator=", ">
                </xsl:for-each>
            </relation>
        </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test=".[@type='child_of']">
            <relation>child of 
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($trt/@rel, ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/firstname, key('ids',substring-after(.,'#'))/lastname"  separator=", ">
                </xsl:for-each>
            </relation>
        </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In particular Saxon tells me "Cannot call the key() function when the context item is not a node"

Thanks for any suggestions.

Nb. corrected xml and xsl errors

Comment: Tomalak I saw that, but here the logic is inverse - the `#`is **not** in the xml id being keyed on,  but in the value passed to the key. My code above includes that.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Comment doesn't apply. :)

Comment: Note that with XSLT/XPath 2 or 3, to find elements by their `xml:id` attribute, you don't need to define a key and use the `key` function, you can simply use the `id` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-id. It has the same caveat like the `key` that you need a context node but if you store that as suggested in the answer you can directly select all referenced elements with `id(tokenize($trt/@rel, ' ')!substring(., 2), $doc)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context item is changed in `<xsl:for-each>`.

When you iterate a list of tokens generated by `tokenize()`, then the context item during each iteration will not be a node, but an `xs:string`.

`key()` expects the context item to be a node. That is because an `<xsl:key>` always applies to *all* open documents, and the context item decides from which document matching nodes are chosen. If you don't give an explicit context item in the third argument to `key()`, then the document element of the context item is assumed. And in this particular case `.` is not a node, it belongs to no document, so `key()` is confused.

This can be solved by explicitly passing a valid context item. Storing the document element (of the right document!) in a top-level variable, let's say `$doc`, and using that in the call to `key()` works well. *Any* node that contains the desired matches will work.

That being said, you do way too much copy-paste-programming. How about:

```
<xsl:key name="person" match="person" use="@xml:id"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="/*" />

<xsl:template match="trait">
  <xsl:variable name="self" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(@rel), ' ')">
    <relation>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$self/@type='spouse_of'">spouse of </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$self/@type='parent_of'">parent of </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$self/@type='child_of'">child of </xsl:when>
        <!-- there probably should be an <xsl:otherwise> here -->
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:variable name="p" select="key('person', substring-after(., '#'), $doc)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$p/lastname, $p/firstname" separator=", " />
    </relation>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

You can save lines, temporary variables and make the approach more modular (think internationalization) by using templates more extensively.

```
<xsl:key name="personByRef" match="person" use="concat('#', @xml:id)" />
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="/*" />

<xsl:template match="trait">
  <xsl:variable name="self" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(@rel), ' ')">
    <relation>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$self/@type" mode="label" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('personByRef', ., $doc)" mode="fullname" />
    </relation>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trait/@type[.='spouse_of']" mode="label">spouse of </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="trait/@type[.='parent_of']" mode="label">parent of </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="trait/@type[.='child_of']" mode="label">child of </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person" mode="fullname">
  <xsl:value-of select="lastname,firstname" separator=", " />
</xsl:template>
```

Here the whole block of `"label"` templates could be imported from a language-specific file, without having to touch your logic.

Maybe you want to output full names elsewhere, too - having a single dedicated template for that is useful as well.

Comment: This works great (after your revision), thanks very much. One thing: once the tokenizing code has looked up and output the multiple names from `@rel`, they get reassembled without a delimiter separating the names. I'd like to put a semi-colon between the names....any suggestions on how to introduce this? I know I copy-paste - I'm still getting my head around the idea of templating :)

Comment: You can add something like `<xsl:if test="position() != last()">; </xsl:if>` to the loop.

Comment: (Also see my alternative approach.)